# Do points transform differently from vectors?

Tags: vectors, coordinate-systems, transformation

[In this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3785166/why-does-gradient-change-depending-on-what-coordinate-system-we-take-the-gradien), a point $x$ in the coordinate system $C$ transforms to coordinate system $C'$ as follows:

$x' = \frac{x}{2}$

However, the unit vector $i'$ in the $x'$-direction in $C'$ is $2i$ where $i$ is the unit vector in the x-direction in $C$.

What is the reason for this discrepancy? Are points and vectors transformed differently?

Comment: In transforming the unit vector in $x'$ to $2i$ you are doing the equivalent to changing your unit of measurement (in that direction) from $5$ mm to $10$ mm, as an example. Therefore, since the object measured doesn't change, what used to measure $4$ units, now it measures $2$ units. The math terminology for this is that vectors transform contra-variantly: their coefficients ($4$ or $2$ in the example) transform in the opposite direction as the vectors themselves.

Comment: Hm, thne shouldn't is gradient not contravariant vector?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$(x_1,x_2, \cdots)*({\bf i}, {\bf j} , \cdots)^T = (x'_1,x'_2, \cdots)*({\bf {i'}}, {\bf{ j'}} , \cdots)^T$

so if $({\bf {i'}}, {\bf{ j'}} , \cdots)^T= {\bf T} ({\bf i}, {\bf j} , \cdots)^T$ then ..